# One-to-one assignment in Google sheets with data validation

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, auto-update

Is it possible to add a data validation dropdown to each cell in a column such that available values are consumed and removed from the dropdown once selected, so that only one cell can receive a given value and there are no duplicate selections? I'm not interested in highlighting duplicates, I want to remove a value from available options once selected by another cell.

Comment: You could use onEdit() to remove the selected validation value from the validation range or list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach it by adding another sheet to your spreadsheet. Lets call this sheet **Settings**. In that sheet, list all the available option in Column A. Then in Column B add a formula which checks, if that particular value has already been selected. If it is, then just make it empty, otherwise return its value.

```
=IF( ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1, *theColumnWhereTheDropDownIst*, 0)), "", A1 )
```

So now, in Column B, only those values will be shown which are still free. Lets name this range "unusedValues".

Then, in your range where you want the pick-list, add data-validation and set it to "unusedValues". It should now work.

This approach is easy to use and modify. It does not require apps-script.

Comment: This strategy works. There's a side effect that as soon as you choose the value, it's marked as invalid, but this can be ignored.

Comment: I don't understand the exact problem. On my end it works without problems. Please explain and I'll help.